# My fan is constantly running even if my laptop doesn't do much work

Tags: 16.04, sound, lenovo, fan

I have recently purchased a Lenovo Ideapad 510s with an Intel Core i5 Kaby Lake and 8GB of RAM and I fired up Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I installed a few programs but didn't play with any driver setting whatsoever.

However, my fan is constantly causing a reasonable amount of noise. It sounds normal, but it is kind of loud. I don't have this problem on Windows.

Right now, as I'm typing this, I can hear the fan it's running at a constant speed. Here's a snapshot of my output after running `top -o %CPU`:
[image]

As you can't see, there isn't much running. What should I do? I will provide aditional information if needeed.